# What is the difference between these two Ruby symbols?

Tags: ruby, symbols, objectid, splat

I discovered this after playing around with object ids.

```
ObjectSpace._id2ref(2648)
=> :**
ObjectSpace._id2ref(6688)
=> :**
ObjectSpace._id2ref(2648) == ObjectSpace._id2ref(6688)
=> false
```

The first one is the symbol for the exponentiation operator;

```
2.send(ObjectSpace._id2ref(2648), 3)
=> 8
2.send(ObjectSpace._id2ref(6688), 3)
NoMethodError: undefined method `**' for 2:Fixnum
```

But the second one somehow isn't? I assume they just look the same after being passed to #print. But what *is* the difference? Is one of them somehow a unicode symbol?

UPDATE: The second one is probably the new double splat for keyword arguments, but I can't seem to verify this.

Comment: In which Ruby version you are ? I got **Range error**. 2.0.0-p-353

Comment: Weird. From `pry -v` I get `Pry version 0.9.12.6 on Ruby 2.0.0`.

Comment: Object ids aren't necessarily the same across Ruby invocations so there's not much anyone can say unless you can provide explicit steps that reproduce what you're seeing. OTOH, `id = ':**'.object_id; puts ObjectSpace._id2ref(id)` is suggestive so why not check the class of the `_id2ref` return values?

Comment: @muistooshort You raised valid point.

Comment: It indeed raise an range error as Arup says, but it further says `RangeError: 0x00000000001a20 is not symbol id value`, so that number seems to fit in the possible range for symbol objects.

Comment: @muistooshort Interesting! I can't find a more deterministic way to produce the second object. I found them by running the equivalent of `10000.times{ |n| ObjectSpace._id2ref(n).inspect }`.

Comment: What is the value of `ObjectSpace._id2ref(6688).to_s.codepoints`? It could be some odd character, possibly U+2217: ASTERISK OPERATOR (which is 8727 in decimal).

Comment: Both objects return `[42, 42]`. Very mysterious...

Comment: @AlexAltair Yes, I’ve managed to reproduce it now, I get them at `object_id` 2648 and 6728 on my machine.

Comment: I suspect this might have something to do with keyword arguments, which use `**` to indicate an options hash in an arguments list. I can’t reproduce the issue on 1.9.3. It looks like there is an extra ‘hidden’ `**` symbol that doesn’t appear in the symbol table but can be found by looking at ObjectSpace.

Comment: Hm... I think you're probably right. I can't find a way to verify it using #send. Are splat and double splat even proper methods? What are they called on? Mysteries abound.

Answer (score 1):

These commands may be illuminating:

```
ObjectSpace._id2ref(2648).class.ancestors
ObjectSpace._id2ref(6688).class.ancestors
```

Comment: Alas, as they are both symbols, this only tells us things about all symbols.